# visibility: visible and youtube

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, youtube

I have a menu created with `ul`/`li` lists.

To create a nice effect, I have the following css:

```
#menu ul { 

    /* ... */

    visibility:hidden; 

    /* ... */

} 

#menu li:hover > ul {
    /* ... */ 

    visibility: visible;

    /* ... */
}
```

You can view the full code here: http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-animated-dropdown-menu.

The menu works fine without any issues unless I embed a Youtube video (e.g. a random video - `<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/e80qhyovOnA?rel=0" frameborder="0" width="420" height="315"></iframe>`).

I have troubleshooted the problem to the visibility css property and when using Chrome.

Is there a way I can change the CSS to keep the bouncing effect?

Replacing this with `display:none` works but it looses the bouncing effect. There seems to be a conflict with Youtube's code. Ideally I do not touch anything within the `iframe` unless it is automated as videos are embedded via `WYSIWYG`.

Thank you.

Comment: "The menu works fine without any issues unless I embed a Youtube video" -- so what happens when you *do* embed a YouTube video? You kind of neglected to explain that. Or give a sample we could observe the problem at.

Comment: The drop-down (activated by mouse-over) does not work when the youtube video is embedded.  I cannot show a sample but it can easily be replicated by visiting this page http://www.red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/css3-animated-dropdown-menu-demo.html in Chrome then click About or Cancel (it has to be an option which does not have an sub-menus to replicate), press F12, edit the html code and place any youtube iframe just after the <h2> tag.  Then hover on the Work or Categories menu and you will not see the sub-menus at all.  It seems that the visibility tag conflicts with youtube.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube CSS makes something wrong with transitions, so, just change

```
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
```

to

```
-webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
```

It helps me a lot.